# UIViewController jump to another Controller failed

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

```
 import UIKit
 var map = [Int](count: 81, repeatedValue: 0)
 var allPoint = [[Point]]()
 var allButton = [[UIButton]]()
 var cat = Point(row: 4, col: 4)

class gameController: UIViewController {
var catImageView:UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let bgImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
    bgImage.image = UIImage(named: "bg.png")
    self.view.addSubview(bgImage)
    constructButton()
    constructCat()
    constructRandomWall(false)
}
func constructButton()
{
    for row in 0...8
    {
        var rowButton = [UIButton]()
        var button = UIButton()
        for col in 0...8
        {

            if row % 2 == 0
            {
                button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(45+30*col), CGFloat(250+35*row), CGFloat(30), CGFloat(30)))
            }else
            {
                button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(60+30*col), CGFloat(250+35*row), CGFloat(30), CGFloat(30)))
            }
            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("ClickButton:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "unClick.png"), forState: .Normal)
            self.view.addSubview(button)
            rowButton.append(button)
        }
        allButton.append(rowButton)
    }
}

func constructCat()
{
    catImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(45+30*4), CGFloat(250+35*3), CGFloat(30), CGFloat(60)))
    catImageView.image = UIImage(named:"Cat.png")
    catImageView.animationImages = (1...3).map({return UIImage(named: "cat\($0).png")!})
    catImageView.animationDuration = NSTimeInterval(1.0)
    catImageView.startAnimating()
    self.view.addSubview(catImageView)
}

func constructRandomWall(isAgain:Bool)
{
    var countWall = 0
    let limit: UInt32 = 30
    let result = Int(arc4random() % limit) + 10
    initMarkMap(isAgain)
    var i = 0,j = 0
    while(countWall < result)
    {
        i = Int(arc4random() % 9)
        j = Int(arc4random() % 9)
        if i == 4 && j == 4
        {
            continue
        }
        if  map[i*9+j] == 0
        {
            map[i*9+j] = 1
            allButton[i][j].setImage(UIImage(named: "Click.png"), forState: .Normal)
            allButton[i][j].enabled = false
            ++countWall
        }
    }
    buildPath()
}

func initMarkMap(isAgain:Bool)
{
    for index in 0...80
    {
        map[index] = 0
    }
    constructPointToButton(isAgain)
}

func constructPointToButton(isAgain:Bool)
{
    if isAgain
    {
        for i in 0...8
        {
            for j in 0...8
            {
                allPoint[i][j].cost = 82
                allPoint[i][j].connection = 0
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for i in 0...8
        {
            var rowPoint = [Point]()
            for j in 0...8
            {
                let point = Point(row: i, col: j)
                point.cost = 82
                point.connection = 0
                rowPoint.append(point)
            }
            allPoint.append(rowPoint)
        }
    }

}
func buildPath()
{
    //左上
    for i in 0...8
    {    for j in 0...8
    {
        allPoint[j][i].constructMinPath()
        allPoint[i][j].constructMinPath()

        }
    }

    //左下
    for i in 0...8
    {    for j in 0...8
    {
        allPoint[8-i][j].constructMinPath()
        allPoint[8-j][i].constructMinPath()
        }
    }

    //右上
    for i in 0...8
    {    for j in 0...8
    {
        allPoint[i][8-j].constructMinPath()
        allPoint[j][8-i].constructMinPath()
        }
    }

    //右下
    for i in 0...8
    {
        for j in 0...8
        {
            allPoint[8-i][8-j].constructMinPath()
            allPoint[8-j][8-i].constructMinPath()
        }
    }
}

func ClickButton(sender:UIButton)
{
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "Click.png"), forState: .Normal)
    sender.enabled = false
    start()
}

func start()
{
    let getDirection = getGoLocation()
    //show()
    //print("row = \(getDieection!.row) col = \(getDieection!.col)")
    let row = getDirection.row
    let col = getDirection.col
    cat.row = row
    cat.col = col
    if row % 2 == 0
    {
        catImageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(45+30*col), CGFloat(250+35*(row-1)), CGFloat(30), CGFloat(60))
    }
    else
    {
        catImageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(60+30*col), CGFloat(250+35*(row-1)), CGFloat(30), CGFloat(60))
    }
    if cat.judgeInBorder()
    {
        end(0)
    }
    else if cat.conNotGo()
    {
        end(1)
    }

}

func getGoLocation() -> Point
{
    buildPath()
    let canGo = cat.getAllenbalePoint()
    var p:Point = cat
    var min = 8200
    if canGo.count > 0
    {
        for value in canGo
        {
            let temp = (value?.cost)!
            print("temp = \(temp)");
            if(min > temp)
            {
                min = temp
                p = value!
                print("min = \(temp)");
            }
            else if min == temp
            {
                if p.connection < value!.connection
                {
                    min = (value?.cost)!
                    p = value!
                }
            }
        }
        print("最后走的点row = \(p.row)  col = \(p.col)）", separator: "", terminator: "\n")
        return p
    }
    else
    {
        return p
    }
}

func end(result:Int)
{
    var alert:UIAlertController!
    if result == 0
    {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "游戏结束", message: "你输了", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    }
    else
    {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "游戏结束", message: "你赢了", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    }
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "退出游戏", style: .Default, handler: {
        (ac:UIAlertAction) in self.DidExit()
    })
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "重来一次", style: .Default, handler: {
        (ac:UIAlertAction) in self.startAgain()
    })
    alert.addAction(action1)
    alert.addAction(action2)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func startAgain()
{
    //Button
    for row in 0...8
    {
        for col in 0...8
        {
            allButton[row][col].setImage(UIImage(named: "unClick.png"), forState: .Normal)
            allButton[row][col].enabled = true
        }
    }
    //Wall
    constructRandomWall(true)
    //Cat
    catImageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(45+30*4), CGFloat(250+35*3), CGFloat(30), CGFloat(60))
    cat.row = 4
    cat.col = 4
}
//    func show()
//    {
//        for var i = 0 ;i<=8 ;++i
//        {
//            for var j = 0; j <= 8; ++j
//            {
//                print(allPoint[i][j].cost, separator: "", terminator: "\t")
//            }
//            print("", separator: "", terminator: "\n")
//        }
//    }

func DidExit()
{
    exit(0)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}

import UIKit

class showView: UIViewController {
var number:Int
var image:UIImageView!
init(number:Int)
{
    self.number = number
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
        image.image = UIImage(named: "start\(number)")
    if number == 2
    {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/3-10,y: self.view.frame.height-180,width: self.view.frame.width/3+20,height: 70))
            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("startGame"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            button.setTitle("StartGame", forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(image)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.addSubview(image)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
import UIKit

class showView: UIViewController {
var number:Int
var image:UIImageView!
init(number:Int)
{
    self.number = number
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
        image.image = UIImage(named: "start\(number)")
    if number == 2
    {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/3-10,y: self.view.frame.height-180,width: self.view.frame.width/3+20,height: 70))
            button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("startGame"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            button.setTitle("StartGame", forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(image)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.addSubview(image)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

The above is my part of the code,I try to jump to gameController in ViewController,In code value is equal to true, but it does not perform jumps can you help me?

[image]
[image]

Comment: please add showControll() code.

Comment: Please wait a moment.

Comment: First of all, the method where you try to present another controller may be called while the original controller is not performed itself. Secondly, from the code you posted we have no idea which method is going to be called and more importantly what it does. Note: whenever you have something to add to the question (e.g. a code snippet) please add it by editing the question, not by writing to the comments - a place to have a discussion.

Comment: gameController() too. The whole class would be easier.

Comment: I finished the update

Comment: @adolfosrs . Just have some trouble.so the edits too late.Sorry.